# cannot hit the servlet via https from nokia mobile using j2me

Tags: java-me, https, nokia, mobile-application

Im developing a mobile application in j2me.Im using "Nokia c2-01" mobile for testing.In my application i send a request to one servlet and receive response to mobile via GPRS.I send the request to the servlet through ("https://" ).Here one problem is when i send a request to the server.The request is not hit to server when it goes from mobile application ,but it hits succesfully and get response succefully from server when i type the address ("https://61.......") in the mobile phone's web browser.
  Here i cannot identify why i cannot able to send the request via my application running in mobile (but it sends succeffully from the mobile phone's browser)
  My source code snippet is given below

```
HttpsConnection httpsConnection=(HttpsConnection)Connector.open(url);
  InputStream is=httpsConnection.openInputStream();
```

Here the urs starts from "https://" some url.In my mobile app it throws the "CertificationException".But from mobile phone's web browser it works correctly.
Please any one give me ur ideas about this issues.

Comment: what is the exact stack trace of the CertificateException? There are a lot of devices (esp. the cheap ones) with a J2ME stack which lacks a complete SSL implementation (which is needed for doing https).

Comment: Hi when i use the url "httpsL://onlinesbi.com" (It is a state bank of india's web site) it hits the servlet (server) succeffully from the my test mobile phone (nokia c2 01)'s web browser and it also successfully hits from my mobile application also.So i think my phone supports Https.I think there is any changes is needed in the mobile phone's setting.Please help me its an urgent issue.

Comment: Hi when i use the url "https://www.onlinesbi.com" (It is a state bank of india's web site) it hits the servlet (server) succeffully from my test mobile phone (nokia c2 01)'s web browser and it also successfully hits from my mobile application also.So i think my phone supports Https.I think there is any changes is needed in the mobile phone's setting.Please help me its an urgent issue.  (Sorry for some mmistakes in previous comments).

Comment: Hi when i use the url "https://www.onlinesbi.com";(https://www.onlinesbi.com) (It is a state bank of india's web site) it hits the servlet (server) succeffully from my test mobile phone (nokia c2 01)'s web browser and it also successfully hits from my mobile application also.So i think my phone supports Https.I think there is any changes is needed in the mobile phone's setting.Please help me its an urgent issue. (Sorry for some mmistakes in previous comments)

Comment: Hi,  im using test certificate (self signed) in server side.But i does not put the certificate into mobile phone.Here one thing is when i type the url in the web browser of mobile phone it works   fine.I think if certificate problem means it is not also work from web browser of mobile phone.Im also tested in "Sony erricson z530i" mobile it works fine.But based on project requirements here my target phone is nokia.If there is any mistake on my comment please forgive me.On past 20 days im not able to solve the issues .So please help me to solve the issues.All ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using a test certificate? Probably phone does not have the ssl root certificate that you are using on the server and therefore refusing to connect to the server. You can use a proper certificate or try to install your certificate to your test phone.

Comment: Hi,  im using test certificate (self signed) in server side.But i does not put into mobile phone.Here one thing is when i type the url in the web browser of mobile phone it works correctly.I think if certificate problem means it is not also work from web browser of mobile phone.

Comment: Do you get any prompts when connecting to your test site with the phone's browser. Also you may check if the browser settings have the alerts for unsecure enabled. Does CertificationException have any details?